# Python numpy index set from Boolean array

Tags: python, numpy

How do I transform a Boolean array into an iterable of indexes?

E.g.,

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it
x = np.array([1,0,1,1,0,0])
y = x > 0
retval = [i for i, y_i in enumerate(y) if y_i]
```

Is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [`np.nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero).

```
x = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0])
np.where(x)[0] # returns a tuple hence the [0], see help(np.where)
# array([0, 2, 3])
x.nonzero()[0] # in this case, the same as above.
```

See `help(np.where)` and `help(np.nonzero)`.

Possibly worth noting that in the `np.where` page it mentions that for 1D `x` it's basically equivalent to your longform in the question.

Comment: I knew there was a better way!  I looked at "np.index*", but didn't find anything.